# How to select only one element inside of table / div?

Tags: javascript, jquery

**Objective:**

1. Select one year from list table
2. Have the ability to change year (if clicked by accident)
3. Reload all of the years
4. Select a different year

jQuery: (this is my failed hacked attempt; please suggest a proper implementation)

```
$('#year tr td').click(function() {
  $('#year tr td').removeClass('selected');
  var year = $(this).addClass('selected');
  $('#year').hide();
  $('#vehicle_year').prepend(year).show();
});

$('#reset').click(function() {
  $("[prepended=yes]", "#vehicle_year").remove();
  $('#vehicle_year').hide();
  $('#year tr td').removeClass('selected');
  $('#year').show();
});
```

html:

```
<span id="vehicle_year" style="display: none"> <span id="reset">(change year)</span> </span>
<table id="year" class="vehicle_options">
    <tbody><tr>
      <td id="1980">1980</td>
      <td id="1981">1981</td>
      <td id="1982">1982</td>
      <td id="1983">1983</td>
      <td id="1984">1984</td>
      <td id="1985">1985</td>
      <td id="1986">1986</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td id="1987">1987</td>
      <td id="1988">1988</td>
      <td id="1989">1989</td>
      <td id="1990">1990</td>
      <td id="1991">1991</td>
      <td id="1992">1992</td>
      <td id="1993">1993</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td id="1994">1994</td>
      <td id="1995">1995</td>
      <td id="1996">1996</td>
      <td id="1997">1997</td>
      <td id="1998">1998</td>
      <td id="1999">1999</td>
      <td id="2000">2000</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td id="2001">2001</td>
      <td id="2002">2002</td>
      <td id="2003">2003</td>
      <td id="2004">2004</td>
      <td id="2005">2005</td>
      <td id="2006">2006</td>
      <td id="2007">2007</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td id="2008">2008</td>
      <td id="2009">2009</td>
      <td id="2010">2010</td>
      <td id="2011">2011</td>
      <td id="2012">2012</td>
      <td id="2013">2013</td>
      <td id="2014">2014</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td id="2015">2015</td>
    </tr>
</tbody></table>
```

**jsFiddle**: http://jsfiddle.net/32ta6/

Comment: I didn't downvote you. However, you can make your life a lot simpler by adding the years to a drop down (i.e. `<select></select>`)...

Comment: What's wrong with this implementation?  You don't have a single div in your html BTW

Comment: The #year div. And See the fiddle. It doesn't let you change the year.

Comment: @War10ck `select` doesn't provide the user experience I am after here

Comment: Ah the year table.  gotcha

Comment: Please include the relevant HTML markup in your OP.  We cannot rely on the demo for this.

Comment: It works for me? http://jsfiddle.net/32ta6/

Comment: @marko after you select a year and you try to change it, the original year is no longer listed. That isn't what I want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you go, it is similar to ps2goat, but removed code that wasn't needed and fixed the year from being removed.

http://jsfiddle.net/32ta6/7/

```
//select year
$('#year tr td').click(function() {
 // $('#year tr td').removeClass('selected');
  var year = $(this).text();
  $('#year').hide();
  $('#selectedYear').html(year);
  $('#vehicle_year').show();
});

$('#reset').click(function() {
  //$("[prepended=yes]", "#vehicle_year").remove();
  $('#vehicle_year').hide();
  //$('#year tr td').removeClass('selected');
  $('#year').show();
});
```

<

```
table id="year" class="vehicle_options">
    <tbody><tr>
      <td id="1980">1980</td>
      <td id="1981">1981</td>
      <td id="1982">1982</td>
      <td id="1983">1983</td>
      <td id="1984">1984</td>
      <td id="1985">1985</td>
      <td id="1986">1986</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td id="1987">1987</td>
      <td id="1988">1988</td>
      <td id="1989">1989</td>
      <td id="1990">1990</td>
      <td id="1991">1991</td>
      <td id="1992">1992</td>
      <td id="1993">1993</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td id="1994">1994</td>
      <td id="1995">1995</td>
      <td id="1996">1996</td>
      <td id="1997">1997</td>
      <td id="1998">1998</td>
      <td id="1999">1999</td>
      <td id="2000">2000</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td id="2001">2001</td>
      <td id="2002">2002</td>
      <td id="2003">2003</td>
      <td id="2004">2004</td>
      <td id="2005">2005</td>
      <td id="2006">2006</td>
      <td id="2007">2007</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td id="2008">2008</td>
      <td id="2009">2009</td>
      <td id="2010">2010</td>
      <td id="2011">2011</td>
      <td id="2012">2012</td>
      <td id="2013">2013</td>
      <td id="2014">2014</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td id="2015">2015</td>
    </tr>
</tbody></table>


<span id="vehicle_year" style="display: none"><span id="selectedYear"></span> <span id="reset">(change year)</span> </span>
```

Answer (score 0):

Check out the fiddle here.  basically, your call to `$('#vehicle_year').prepend(year).show();` puts the value in open `<html>` tags where it will be extremely difficult to retrieve.

http://jsfiddle.net/32ta6/12/

```
<table id="year" class="vehicle_options">
    <tbody><tr>
      <td id="1980">1980</td>
      <td id="1981">1981</td>
      <td id="1982">1982</td>
      <td id="1983">1983</td>
      <td id="1984">1984</td>
      <td id="1985">1985</td>
      <td id="1986">1986</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td id="1987">1987</td>
      <td id="1988">1988</td>
      <td id="1989">1989</td>
      <td id="1990">1990</td>
      <td id="1991">1991</td>
      <td id="1992">1992</td>
      <td id="1993">1993</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td id="1994">1994</td>
      <td id="1995">1995</td>
      <td id="1996">1996</td>
      <td id="1997">1997</td>
      <td id="1998">1998</td>
      <td id="1999">1999</td>
      <td id="2000">2000</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td id="2001">2001</td>
      <td id="2002">2002</td>
      <td id="2003">2003</td>
      <td id="2004">2004</td>
      <td id="2005">2005</td>
      <td id="2006">2006</td>
      <td id="2007">2007</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td id="2008">2008</td>
      <td id="2009">2009</td>
      <td id="2010">2010</td>
      <td id="2011">2011</td>
      <td id="2012">2012</td>
      <td id="2013">2013</td>
      <td id="2014">2014</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td id="2015">2015</td>
    </tr>
</tbody></table>


<span id="vehicle_year" style="display: none"><span id="selectedYear"></span> <span id="reset">(change year)</span> </span>
```

javascript:

```
//select year
$('#year tr td').click(function() {
  $('#year tr td').removeClass('selected');
  var year = $(this).addClass('selected').prop('innerText');
  $('#year').hide();
  $('#selectedYear').html(year);
  $('#vehicle_year').show();
});

$('#reset').click(function() {
  $('#vehicle_year').hide();
  $('#year tr td').removeClass('selected');
  $('#year').show();
});
```

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/32ta6/   -- doesnt work .. when you click change year the original year click is missing.

Comment: ok, I updated the example.  the DOM element was being moved in the previous example.  I changed this to just assign the innerText to the year variable.  http://jsfiddle.net/32ta6/12/

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#year tr td').click(function() {
  var that = $(this); 
  var year = that.attr("id"); 
  $('#year tr td').removeClass('selected');
  that.addClass('selected');
  $('#year').hide();
  $('#vehicle_year').prepend(year).show();
});
```

This works: http://jsfiddle.net/32ta6/11/